# Exisitng content repository based on Git or Hg?

Tags: git, full-text-search, repository, content-management

I'm looking for a piece of software for managing large content collections, such as 300MB of HTML. It needs branching and merging, and should be distributed if possible (I.e, a dvcs).

Full text indexing is needed.

A web-based interface is desired.

Anything out there? It's a big project that would take me a lot of time to create.

Building it myself, I would combine Git, JGit, Lucene, and the Play framework.

One particular problem is that the 300MB of text is divided into 200,000 files or records. This quantity of files isn't generally fast, so it might be good to skip the standard filesystem working model of git....

Comment: For comparison, an uncompressed copy of the Linux (2.6.30) sources I had laying around is 378 MB in about 37,000 files.

Comment: I recommend actually trying some things before concluding that a filesystem working model isn't going to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention windows compatibility is important.... But not essential.

Comment: what did u use for search/index? Im looking at opengrok..

Answer (score 1):

Well, my answer is GIT.

There is no better Version Control System that can deal with many text based files faster and more reliably than git.

For web based interface - look at CGIT